# Linking strapi with postgresql having postgis extension errors out

Tags: postgresql, postgis, strapi

Am trying to link postgresql database to strapi V4 and my postgresql database has postgis extensions installed. When I run my application I get the following error . Is there a way to fix this ?

Any suggestion or resolution would be of great help

**error: drop table if exists “public”.“us_gaz” - cannot drop table us_gaz because extension address_standardizer_data_us requires it**

This is the system information

Strapi Version: Strapi V4
Operating System: windows 10
Database: posgresql 14
Node Version: v14.17.5
NPM Version: 6.14.14
Yarn Version: 1.22.11

Thanks